# C++ Code Help (While Loop)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
int choice;


cout << "                         Serendipity Booksellers\n";
cout << "                                Main Menu\n";
cout << "\n                      1.  Cashier Module";
cout << "\n                      2.  Inventory Database Module";
cout << "\n                      3.  Report Module";
cout << "\n                      4.  Exit\n";
cout << "\n                      Enter Your Choice: ";
cin >> choice;

while (choice != 4)
{


}


return 0;
```

> Item four on the Main Menu is “Exit,” which allows the user to end the
>   program. Add a loop to the mainmenu.cpp program that causes it to
>   repeatedly display the menu until the user selects item four.

That's my assignment, can anyone help me with what to put in the while statement to accomplish that?

Comment: Given the simplicity of the assignment, I take it you're just starting to learn C++.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do "while the choice is not 4"?

Probably you want to display the menu and ask for another choice, right?
That should already answer your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

For example the loop can look like

```
int choice = 0;

do
{
    cout << "                         Serendipity Booksellers\n";
    cout << "                                Main Menu\n";
    cout << "\n                      1.  Cashier Module";
    cout << "\n                      2.  Inventory Database Module";
    cout << "\n                      3.  Report Module";
    cout << "\n                      4.  Exit\n";
    cout << "\n                      Enter Your Choice: ";

} while ( cin >> choice && choice != 4 );
```

Or

```
do
{
    cout << "                         Serendipity Booksellers\n";
    cout << "                                Main Menu\n";
    cout << "\n                      1.  Cashier Module";
    cout << "\n                      2.  Inventory Database Module";
    cout << "\n                      3.  Report Module";
    cout << "\n                      4.  Exit\n";
    cout << "\n                      Enter Your Choice: ";

    if ( !( cin >> choice ) ) break;

    switch ( choice )
    {
    case 1:
    case 2;
    case 3:
    default:
        cout << "Let's repeat one more!" << endl;
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << "Bye!" << endl;
        break;
    }
} while ( choice != 4 );
```

Comment: Is there a way to just make the menu keep its' state when anything other than 4 is entered? Doing this makes the menu reappear under the initial one instead of just resetting the cin and keeping the menu.

Comment: @ChaosTheory You can try to clear the console window calling for example system command cls: std::system( "cls" ); or some other that clears the screen.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. I truly appreciate it. I saw my post had a -5, sorry if it was poorly done or something.

Answer (score 0):

Just put all the couts and the cin in there

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int choice = 0;
  while (choice != 4)
  {
    cout << "                         Serendipity Booksellers\n";
    cout << "                                Main Menu\n";
    cout << "\n                      1.  Cashier Module";
    cout << "\n                      2.  Inventory Database Module";
    cout << "\n                      3.  Report Module";
    cout << "\n                      4.  Exit\n";
    cout << "\n                      Enter Your Choice: ";
    cin >> choice;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are taking user input for the choice and care for it to repeat the menu for each time the choice is not '4'.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
int choice;

do {

cout << "                         Serendipity Booksellers\n";
cout << "                                Main Menu\n";
cout << "\n                      1.  Cashier Module";
cout << "\n                      2.  Inventory Database Module";
cout << "\n                      3.  Report Module";
cout << "\n                      4.  Exit\n";
cout << "\n                      Enter Your Choice: ";
cin >> choice;
}while (choice != 4);
return 0;
```

P.S.: it is good practice to use 'endl' to end a line rather than "\n"-- e.g.:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()

    {
    int choice;

    do {

    cout << "Serendipity Booksellers" << endl;
    cout << "Main Menu" << endl;
    cout << "1.  Cashier Module" << endl;
    cout << "2.  Inventory Database Module" << endl;
    cout << "3.  Report Module" << endl;
    cout << "4.  Exit" << endl;
    cout << "Enter Your Choice: " << endl;
    cin >> choice;

    } while (choice != 4);
    return 0;
```